# In Perforce, how do I find the local path for files in a pending changelist?

Tags: perforce

Given a Perforce changelist number, I want to find the local path of all files in that pending changelist.

- **p4 describe changelist** -- gets me the depot path for files in the changelist (method 1)
- **p4 opened -c changelist** -- gets me the depot path for files in the changelist (method 2)
- **p4 have** -- gets me the depot path and local path for all files that have previously been submitted

Using a combination of **p4 describe** and **p4 have**, I can find the local paths for all files in the changelist that have previously been submitted to Perforce (and are opened for **delete** or **edit**).

But what about files that are opened for **add**? **p4 have** does not know anything about files that are opened for **add**.

Given a pending Perforce changelist, how do I find the local path for files that are about to be added to Perforce?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To output the local path of all pending adds of a changelist you can use:

```
p4 opened -c changelist | grep -w add | sed 's/#.*//' \
| p4 -x - where | awk '/^\// {print $3}'
```

This does the same without grep but is a bit more obscure:

```
p4 opened -c changelist | sed -n 's/\(.*\)#.*- add .*/\1/p' \
| p4 -x - where | awk '/^\// {print $3}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. There's one thing to note with "p4 where" -- if a file is mapped multiple times in the client spec, then "p4 where" will incorrectly return the first mapping, instead of the last mapping which is where the file really ended up.

Comment: That sounds like an error, `p4 where` is supposed to follow the client view. If you have support, file a bug with perforce.

Comment: Is the problem to do with `{print $3}`?

Comment: @tenpn, Thanks to draw attention to this again. I finally tried multiple mappings myself. `p4 where` outputs multiple lines in this case and only the one starting with '//' is the correct one. I corrected my answer for this case.

Answer (score 8):

You could of course also use

```
p4 -ztag opened -c changelist
```

This will report both the depotFile and the clientFile for each opened file.
To list only client files:

```
p4 -ztag opened -c changelist | grep clientFile | awk '{print $3}'
```

Replacing //client/ with the client's root is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Remember that awk has grep capability, so you can shorten that to:

`p4 -ztag opened -c changelist | awk '/clientFile/ {print $3}'`

Answer (score 7):

Local path for all files in a pending changelist without any external or platform-specific tools:

```
p4 -F %clientFile% fstat -Ro -F action=add [-e CHANGE] //...
```

Remove the '-F action=add' if you want to get files opened for all actions.

Answer (score 2):

```
p4 opened -s -c <changelist#> | awk -F " " '{print $1}' | p4 -x - where | awk -F " " '{print $3}'
```

Comment: Of all the answers posted, this is the only one that actually works for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Peter G's answer, translated into powershell 2.0:

```
p4 opened -c changelist 
    | Where-Object{$_ -match "add"}
    | ForEach-Object{p4 where ($_.split('#')[0])}
    | ForEach-Object{$_.split()[2]}
```