# Get local location for Perforce opened files

Tags: linux, perforce

I want to write a script to process files that have been edited.  `p4 opened` gives a good list but it is using depot syntax.  Is there a way to get the output in local syntax so I can pass the results to my script?

I am running Perforce on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`p4 where`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/where.html) will tell you where a depot file is located locally.

You'll need to take the output of `p4 opened` and use `p4 where` to translate each depot path to a local path.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5749842/99377) might provide some hints.

Edit: Also see if `p4 -ztag opened` suits your needs. `-ztag` frequently produces a more verbose, but script-friendly output.

Comment: @StephenRasku See my edit about `-ztag`. If you're using `p4 opened` in a script, `-ztag` will likely help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the client syntax for the file you can use the
'p4 -Ztag opened' command such as either of the following examples:

```
$ p4 -Ztag opened | grep clientFile
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jambase.html
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jamfile.html
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jamlang.html
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/images/jamgraph-jam.gif
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/index.html


$ p4 -Ztag opened | grep clientFile | cut -d ' ' -f3
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jambase.html
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jamfile.html
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jamlang.html
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/images/jamgraph-jam.gif
//admin14streams/depot/www/dev/index.html
```

The 'p4 where' command will give you the local file system
location if that is what you want, however.

```
$ p4 where //depot/www/dev/Jam.html
//depot/www/dev/Jam.html //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html /home/bruno/myspaces/admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html


$ p4 -Ztag where //depot/www/dev/Jam.html
... depotFile //depot/www/dev/Jam.html
... clientFile //admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html
... path /home/bruno/myspaces/admin14streams/depot/www/dev/Jam.html
```

Hope this helps.